# Find minimum value and assign it in same order to new variable - C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector which has 4 coordinate points, float type. Values are read from the vector and stored in 4 different variables. I want to find the smallest x-coordinate value from the four points and assign it as first variable. Remaining variables follow the same order as origin. 
For example: p1 to p4 represent coordinate points.

```
p1=(319.402,213.309)<br/>
p2=(184.437,312.164) <br/>
p3=(54.9806,183.36) <br/>
p4=(187.458,95.2848)<br/>
```

Minimum x-coordinate is 54.9806. After finding the minimum I would like to assign coordinate values to new variables in new order.

```
p1_new=(54.9806,183.36)<br/> 
p2_new=(187.458,95.2848) -was previously p4<br/> 
p3_new=(319.402,213.309) -was previously p1<br/>
p4_new=(184.437,312.164) -was previously p2<br/>
```

The minimum value can differ from one iteration to other.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can simply use sorting algorithm like bubble sort ,quick sort, etc.. Make a vector temporarily to swap values.

Comment: But @AbhishekPanjabi, sorting algorithm sorts values in ascending or descending order. I do not want to sort them. Please see my example.

Comment: You can better do this by making an array of 4 vectors. Then you simply find min and hold it's index in a variable and then simply swap it with 0th index vector in array. Again you must have to create a vector variable to swap values.

Comment: But you swapped couple times. What is the pattern in your output? Why did you swap p2 and p4?

Comment: @AbhishekPanjabi I dont just want to move the minimum value to the first position. Once the minimum x coordinate value is found it has to assigned as first coordinate. These will be followed by remaining variables in same order, something like cyclic.

Comment: @FirstStep Please see I updated the question. I dont want to swap them.

Comment: Then you can do one thing. You find minimum vector and then store it's value in another vector. Now you have to assign like : suppose it is the index 3 you find as minimul. So starting from that index upto 1 do v[I]=v[I-1]; and lastly assign that temporary vectors value to 0th index variable.

Comment: so you want to keep everything the same but swapping the first element with the minimum x element?

Comment: You want to swap or shift ? You told me that you want like cyclic and now your are saying I want to swap. Please clear.

Comment: No swapping all elements. First find minimum x coordinate value, assign it may be to a new variable. Next new variable will be the same variable that was next to minimum x coordinate value and so on. This is what is needed. As mentioned in the example in the question.

Comment: @FirstStep No. Not just swap first one with minimum. It has to be followed by the order.

Comment: Then I already give answer of your question in my 2nd comment. Find minimum . hold it's index and  swap you min value variable  with 0th index using another vector variable .Simple is that.

Comment: Dude. Your English is so confusing. One thing you need to do: Edit your question and make sure you include three things: Input example, the desired output and the actual output. "What do you want to happen and what is happening now"

Comment: Oh really? My language is that bad? Because it is really difficult to explain the question in words, I have stated a clear example in my question. It has the exact values I am working with and shows the exact output I want. If it is still not clear I don't understand what more to do.

Comment: I can't make your example fit your description. In your example the order of the other variables changes compared to their original order wrt each other. - `p4,p1,p2` when I would expect `p1,p2,p4` to keep the original order. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's divide the problem into segments:
a) find the minimal x value 
b) once founded and you got the location in the vector run in a modulu vector's size

code: (and not with too much emphasis on proper style)

```
vector<pair<double, double>> vec = { {319.402,213.309} ,{184.437,312.164 },{54.9806,183.36} ,{187.458,95.2848} }
, vec2;

double minX = vec[0].first;
int minIndx = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < static_cast<int>(vec.size()); i++)
    if (vec[i].first < minX)
    {
        minIndx = i; //saves the index
        minX = vec[i].first; //saves the minX value
    }

vec2.emplace_back(vec[minIndx]); //put it in the result vector (vec2)


//emplace everything else to the result vector modulu vec.size()
for (int i = minIndx + 1; i != minIndx; i = (i + 1) % static_cast<int>(vec.size()))
    vec2.emplace_back(vec[i]);

//prints the result
for (const auto &v: vec2)
    cout << "(" <<v.first << ", " <<v.second << ")\n";
```

Comment: notice you can use <algorithms> like: auto y=  min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()); auto minIndx = vec.end() - y ; and the circular loop will remain the same

Comment: A, thank you so much. Works perfect in 3 cases but gives "Debug Assertion falied"for the last case where the last vector set is minmum. Eg:  vector<pair<double, double>> vec = { { 119.402, 213.309 }, { 84.437, 312.164 }, { 154.9806, 183.36 }, { 18.458, 95.2848 } }, vec2; Can you please tell me what might be the reason for it?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It is very very helpful.

Comment: yes there's a little bug in what i wrote, when it's the last element i believe you should be able to fix it yourself, it's mandatory as programmer to understand and try those things. so what's the problem? the problem is with the circular loop the right loop is : for (int i = (minIndx + 1) % static_cast<int>(vec.size()); i < static_cast<int>(vec.size()) && i != minIndx; i = (i + 1) % static_cast<int>(vec.size()))
  vec2.emplace_back(vec[i]);
why? because what happens if our vector size is 4 and minIndx=3? we're going to an unallocated element.

Comment: Thank you very much @LiorA. For loop should have been "for (int i = (minIndx + 1)... ".